# Store pictures on server

Tags: php, apache

I struggle finding information on where to store images (profiles pictures) in a secure way. In your opinion, is it necessary to store them outside the web directory? 
Isn't it enough to change .htaccess permission?

Comment: At first - what you're trying to protect them from?

Comment: Being accessible by not authenticated people

Comment: facebook doesn't care about it. Is your application require more "security"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want them to be accessible to people who should have permission, then you'd want to put them outside of the web directory.  You can handle serving them in a couple ways: .htaccess, or by a script which will serve them when certain criteria are passed.  Either way, if they're to be protected, you want them inaccessible to the public/anonymous users.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. You mention a script in your question,  how can I serve the picture/file back using the script? Many thanks

Comment: Write a php file that accepts a query string for the image, reads it from file and writes it to output stream. don't forget to adjust content headers to image, otherwise browsers will not show that as image.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want anyone to access them other than your app then you should store them outside of the websites document root. Then only your app with permissions to the file system can access them.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score -2):

They are going to be rendered in a browser anyway?  Anyone can right click on them and save them to their harddrive.  Is it really nessesary to try and hide them?

Mark